# Data to be inserted in online database of a Website when there is no internet

Tags: php, mysql, offline-web-app

I am working on an ERP System(Website) developed in php(Laravel).The requirement which i need to implement is that when ever there is no internet but if a user wants to submit data,he/she could do that and when internet comes and website start working.i want that offline data to be retrieved.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Alas, the answer to this does not fit in a Stack Overflow answer. Sorry to be blunt, but if you’re having to ask this question, I would say that you’re not able to fulfil this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe sound like a workaround. But you could do that by using localStorage of your browser. if you choose this path you have to check periodically whether the internet is available in the client machine. And also check the localstorage to look for data to submit. Of course you'll have to use javascript to check what i'm suggesting

Comment: i am working on a product which is made in Php laravel with MySQL 
Now they want me to build a Windows form desktop application 
But the problem i am facing is that they want this desktop application to save data and push it to online db when there is internet.Can you provide me with any blog or tutorial?

Comment: Hi, i think your options are limited if you decide to go with laravel for offline app. Because if a pc doesn't have internet connection you won't be able to load the web page. So i suggest, move on to native standalone app (probably made by java) and connect that to your laravel API endpoint